# tuple index when invoke with function with dynamic arguments

Tags: python

```
>>> class Test(object):
>>>    def test(self,*arg):
>>>       print(arg[0],arg[1])
>>> p = Test()
>>> t = 2,3
>>> p.test(t)
```

gives me IndexError: tuple index out of range

why is that? and how do i get the value for that tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You passed in just one argument (the whole tuple `(2, 3)`), so only `arg[0]` exists; if you meant the tuple values to be separate arguments, apply them with the `*args` call syntax:

```
p.test(*t)
```

The alternative is to *not* use the `*arg` catchall argument in your function definition:

```
def test(self, arg):
```

Now your function has two *normal* positional arguments, `self` and `arg`. You can only pass in one argument, and if that is your tuple, `arg[0]` and `arg[1]` will work as expected.

Comment: @AFwcxx It was passing `(2, 3)`

Comment: @AFwcxx: No, it'll pass the value `(2, 3)`. `tuple` objects are values too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it was passing (2,3). then shouldn't arg[0] and arg[1] generates 2,3?

Comment: And here I thought I was going to answer this one. Great job Martijn! :D

Comment: @AFwcxx It would have, if you have defined your function as `def test(self, arg):`

Comment: Obviously, p.test(t) is a call with one parameter whatever type t is. Populating arg[0]==2 and arg[1]==3 from one tuple t=(2,3) is the purpose of the tuple unpacking operator.

Answer (score 1):

Using your demo class:

```
>>> class Test(object):
>>>    def test(self,*arg):
>>>       print(arg[0],arg[1])
```

When doing this:

```
>>> p = Test()
>>> t = 2,3
>>> p.test(t)
```

`arg` will have a value of `[(1,2),]`

When doing this:

```
>>> p = Test()
>>> t = 2,3
>>> p.test(*t)
```

`arg` will have a value of `[1,2]`

The `*` in the function means that all remaining arguments (non-keyword) are put into a list for you.

In the first case you send `(1,2)` has a single argument. In the second case the tuple is made into individual arguments using the `*` thus you send in `1` and `2`.

For complete documentation on this refer to this Python article:
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls